# I want my foreignkey values is equal to the user choose

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Good days guys need help for my ForeignKey Relationship in my models, 
i want my foreignkey values is equal to the user choose

Here's my model view

```
class ProjectNameInviToBid(models.Model):
    ProjectName = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Project Name', null=True)
    DateCreated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ProjectName
```

have relations to ProjectNameInviToBid

```
class InviToBid(models.Model):
    today = date.today()
    ProjectName = models.ForeignKey('ProjectNameInviToBid', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    NameOfFile = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Name of File')
    Contract_No = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Contract No')
    Bid_Opening = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Bid Opening')
    Pre_Bid_Conference = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Pre Bid Conference')
    Non_Refundable_Bidder_Fee = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Non Refundable Fee')
    Delivery_Period = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Delivery Period')
    Pdf_fileinvi = models.FileField(max_length=255, upload_to='upload/invitoBid', verbose_name='Upload Pdf File Here')
    Date_Upload = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

This is my form view

```
class invitoBidForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = InviToBid
        fields = ('ProjectName','NameOfFile', 'Contract_No', 'Bid_Opening',
                  'Pre_Bid_Conference', 'Non_Refundable_Bidder_Fee',
                  'Delivery_Period',
                  'Pdf_fileinvi')
```

and Lastly this my view Forms

```
def project_name_details(request, sid):

    majordetails = ProjectNameInviToBid.objects.get(id=sid)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = invitoBidForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            majordetails = form.ProjectName
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'File has been Uploaded')
    else:
        form = invitoBidForm()

    args = {
        'majordetails': majordetails,
        'form': form

    }
    return render(request,'content/invitoBid/bacadmininvitoBid.html', args)
```

but im have a error,, hope you can help me. thank you in advance